# How to interpret an h2o decision tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, h2o

I have graphed an h2o decision tree:[image: Tree]
I was following a lot of posts on SO and correct me if I'm wrong, but the values at the leaves are correlations, the levels are the count of categorical values, and tree 0 means that first tree that was created.
Now my problem is that
1. I can't figure out the "greater or equal" signs and the "smaller than" signs at the categorical values. For example, if we continue after `Z<10.032598`, we have "greater or equal" sign on the right which implies what? Also, we have a "smaller than" sign on the left with `NA` which are the categorical variables but what does "smaller than" a categorical variable even means?
2. If we start at the top (`c`) and go right, we have the value 1, which I understand imply that `c` has 1 correlation. But if we go down 1 level to again `Z<10.032598` , the "greater than or equal" sign on the right imply 1 correlation again. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are constructing a simple decision tree, then the values at leaf nodes are the output probability, not correlation and the levels are not count of categorical values as you can have multiple features repeating in the tree at different levels. The levels are decided by the depth you provide when training the model.

1. The greater than or smaller than sign shows which direction you have to go to. For example at level 1, if `z>10.0325` than you go right but if it is smaller than you go left in the tree. `NA` basically shows that you go left if value is smaller than threshold or is null. Your model is considering categorical variables at numerical and H2O provides you the option to change that using `categorical_encoding`. Since the data is in numerical format, it is interpreted as numerical.
2. The reason there is decision `1` again is because your model is checking a different feature now to verify the results. If first level fails and model is not sure about output, it will check second level and do the same thing and will go further down the tree till it reaches a prediction.

Comment: What do you mean that the levels are decided by the depth? The model has 200 categorical variables so it looks pretty clear that there are 100 on each side of the first node, and 96 and 4 on the last one. And what does probability 1 at ```c``` or probability 1 at ```z>10.0325``` mean?

Comment: That is not how decision tree works... from the image provided, the right subtree from root ends at the first level

Comment: You can see from the tree that the model checks z for a greater threshold and if that fails it checks it for smaller threshold and if it still fails than the prediction is 0.0 else it checks c and makes the final prediction.

Comment: Almost got it, thanks! So if you look at the last level, where there is 96 on the left and 4 categoricals on the right, what does the 96 level means? Does the model check c, and if it has those 4 categoricals the probability is 1, and if its c with 96 other categoricals its 0?

Comment: is your problem binary classification and are you building one tree for every class. In that case the meaning of probability changes but rest will remain same. So verify that. If you are building multiple trees, then the leaf values will show the probability of the prediction to belong to that class.

Comment: This model specifically is binary classification, and I have specified 1 tree only. My goal is to create regression tree (but I had to test it on a basic tree since my regression tree has a lot of categorical values).